Cloning Folder to Existing Name in Azure Storage Explorer
Is there anyway to clone a folder on top of / into (i.e. merge into) another folder in the Azure Storage Explorer?
Using the "Clone Folder" feature leads to:
Failed to clone 'xxx/yyy/'. An object with the new name already exists.

With S3, the folders themselves don't exist, they are just file "prefixes" so the the clone would just involve copying the blobs with new prefixes. Is that not the same on Azure?
this being the tool:


Have you tried Copy/Paste functionality instead of Clone?

Copy and paste works, but then I have to descend into the directory, select all subdirectories copy and then go to target, descend and paste. And of course hope that there is no conflict in names in the subdirectories. A lot more clicking than a top level clone.


With S3, the folders themselves don't exist, they are just file "prefixes" so the the clone would just involve copying the blobs with new prefixes. Is that not the same on Azure?

In Azure Blob Storage it is same, there is no native concept of folders. Instead, blobs are organized into containers, and the blob names can include forward slashes to create a virtual hierarchy.

Failed to clone 'xxx/yyy/'. An object with the new name already exists.

In Azure Storage Explorer, if you try to clone a folder and a folder with the same name already exists, you'll encounter an error. To avoid this, make sure to give the new folder a different name.
I agree with Gaurav Mantri's comment, you can use the copy and paste functionality instead of clone.
Portal:

Now, you can be able to paste the root folder into sample folder.
Portal:

